# Why does grep give "Binary file (standard input) matches"?

Tags: c, file, api, io, pipe

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* cmd = popen("grep Hello", "w");   
    fwrite("Hello\n", 6, 6, cmd);
    fwrite("Hillo\n", 6, 6, cmd);
    fwrite("Hello\n", 6, 6, cmd);   
    pclose(cmd);
}
```

The program above outputs:

> Binary file (standard input) matches

Why does grep give the message, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attempting to write 36 bytes instead of 6, effectively accessing bytes beyond the end of the string.  Definitely undefined behaviour.  Only the first `'\0'` byte is expected.

Use

```
fwrite("Hello\n", 1, 6, cmd);
```

Or more simply:

```
fputs("Hello\n", cmd);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `nul` byte appended by `fwrite()`. The reason your program has issues is because you are `fwrite()`ing 6 elements of size 6 each.

Comment: Undefined behaviour beyond the 7th byte.